# SCALA: Group on one column and Sum on another

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala. The data contained in the input file is:

```
a,abcd,1
a,efaf,3
b,xafsdf,2
b,fafdr,3
```

I need output as follows:

```
a,4
b,5
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {`
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local")`
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`
  val dataRDD = sc.textFile("D:\\scala_samples\\moin.csv")`
  // dataRDD.collect().foreach(println(_))`
  val splitted = dataRDD.map(line => line.split(","))`
  val processed = splitted.map(x=>(x(0),x(2)))`
```

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: This question also need spark so please tag to spark

Answer (score 1):

Just use dataframe semantics.

First read the data as dataframe:

```
val spark = SparkSession.getOrCreate
val df = spark.read.csv(filename)
df.groupby("a").sum
```

EDIT: For the RDD version try:

```
processsed.reduceByKey(_ + _).
```

The above basically assumes processed is an RDD of pairs and you want to sum for each key (first element) the values of the second element.

Comment: Thanks Assaf...Is this not possible via RDD as am getting "Value SparkSession  not found error"

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Comment: Scala IDE 2.1 with Spark compiler version 1.4.0

Comment: The spark version is the reason you didn't find SparkSession. SparkSession is from spark version 2.0.0 onwards. BTW 1.4.0 is a really old version, Spark is currently at 2.3.1...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `reduceByKey()` function . Please find below step by step solution

```
//Creating sample rdd, you can use yours

val dataRDD=sc.parallelize(Array("a,abcd,1","a,efaf,3","b,xafsdf,2","b,fafdr,3"))

//Converting RDD[String] to RDD[(String,Int)] so you can apply reduceByKey function

val dataRDDMap=dataRDD.map(str=>str.split(",")).map(strArr=>(strArr(0),strArr(2).toInt))
val wcRDD=dataRDDMap.reduceByKey(_+_)

//Output:

scala>wcRDD.collect
res6: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((b,5), (a,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is with RDD's `aggregateByKey` operation.

```
val seqOp: (Int, (String, String, Int)) => Int = (accum, current) => accum + current._3
val combainOps: (Int, Int) => Int = (accum, current) => accum + current


val baseRDD = sc.textFile("\data.txt").map { x =>
  val splits = x.split(",")
  (splits(0), (splits(0), splits(1), splits(2).toInt))
}.aggregateByKey(0)(seqOp, combainOps)

baseRDD.foreach(println(_))
```

Note that `map` operation does splitting , parsing, converting record into key pair values instead of creating unnecessary RDDs for each of these steps.

To save RDD into a file,

```
baseRDD.saveAsTextFile("folder path")
```

For more info, refer [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsTextFile(java.lang.String))

**UPDATE**

Doing aggregation on multiple columns with Rdd is bit cumbersome whereas it is simple and elegant with sql.  Updating my solution for sql.  If equivalent solution is required on rdd, keep me posted..

```
import sql.implicits._
        Val df  = rdd.toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")

     import org. apache.spark.sql.functions.sum
        df.groupBy($"col1"). agg(sum("col3"),sum("col4"),sum("col5")).show
```

Comment: Many Thanks Balaji...this worked...can we directly save this to file instead of printing to the screen?

Comment: Hi Balaji, What if we want to sum on multiple columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: multiple column values together or individually ??

Comment: can you please explain your requirement more clearly ?

Comment: Dear Balaji...Data contained in the input file is in the following format:    
a,abcd,2,7,9
a,efaf,3,12,11
b,xafsdf,1,4,8
b,fafdr,3,1,7   
The required output is to group of 1’st column and sum on 3’rd, 4’th and 5’th column

In the above case, the output should be as follows:

a, 4, 19, 20
b,  4, 5, 15

Comment: Thanks Balaji...Am working on SCALA IDE using MAVEN sbt on windows. The errors that I am encountering while running the updated code are 1.object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql 2. not found: value SparkSession and 3. not found: value sql

Comment: you can create sql like below..
val sql  = new SqlContext(sc)